# Angularjs ng-class how to mix conditional and array (switch) class selection

Tags: angularjs

I got a selected class and some classes depending of on var as

```
{selected_class : model.is_selected}
```

and

```
{on:'on_class', off:'off_class', wait: 'wait_class'}[model.state]
```

How can I mix these two in a ng-class directive?

Comment: Your question isn't too clear. Can you please show the complete relevant controller code?

Comment: I woulg like to combine the first for exemple when user click on the element to show it selected and the second one to reflect the current state of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Like this.  I don't know a "cleverer" way:

```
ng-class="{selected_class : model.is_selected, 
  on_class: model.state=='on',
  off_class: model.state=='off',
  wait_class: model.state=='wait'}"
```

Comment: Hi, I was searching a more concise way without to have to repeat the test, Hence the "Array" switch for this part and a simple comparison for the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to apply multiple classes, you can just write a longer `ng-class` expression:

```
ng-class="{'selected_class': model.is_selected, 'on_class': model.state == 'on', 'off_class': model.state == 'off', 'wait_class': model.state == 'wait'}
```